# FactoryBeanNotInitializedException: Cannot determine target class for proxy

Tags: java, spring, pool

I want to setup an object pool in my spring application with annotation only.
I started out with this example taken from Spring docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop-api.html#aop-ts-pool.

Here is how I translate the XML configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class SpringObjectPoolTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(SpringObjectPoolTest.class) //
                .addCommandLineProperties(false) //
                .web(false) //
                .headless(false) //
                .registerShutdownHook(true) //
                .application() //
                .run();

        context.getBean(SpringObjectPoolTest.class).go();
    }

    @Resource(name = "pfb")
    private FactoryBean<MyTask> pool;

    @Resource(name="pool")
    private TargetSource targetSource;

    private static ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    @Bean(name = "task")
    @Scope("prototype")
    public MyTask createNewTask() {
        return new MyTask();
    }

    @Bean(name = "pool")
    public CommonsPoolTargetSource setupObjectPool() {
        CommonsPoolTargetSource pc = new CommonsPoolTargetSource();
        pc.setMaxSize(25);
        pc.setTargetBeanName("task");

        return pc;
    }

    @Bean(name = "pfb")
    public ProxyFactoryBean createProxyFactoryBean() {
        ProxyFactoryBean pfb = new ProxyFactoryBean();
        pfb.setTargetSource(targetSource);

        return pfb;
    }

    private void go() {
        try {
            pool.getObject().speak();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

However I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: 
   Error creating bean with name 'pfb':  
org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBeanNotInitializedException: 
   Cannot determine target class for proxy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are a bit over engineering this. Spring already knows how to inject a proxied `MyTask`, there is no need to have a `FactoryBean<MyTask>` or to call `getObject()` on the pool. In "pooledTask" below Spring knows that by injecting a `ProxyFactoryBean` ("pfb") it will actually inject the instance that factory bean creates, not the factory bean itself. Here's how I'd do it:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class SpringObjectPoolTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(SpringObjectPoolTest.class) //
                .addCommandLineProperties(false) //
                .web(false) //
                .headless(false) //
                .registerShutdownHook(true) //
                .application() //
                .run();

        context.getBean(SpringObjectPoolTest.class).go();
    }

    private static ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    @Resource(name = "pfb")
    private MyTask pooledTask;

    @Resource(name="pool")
    private CommonsPoolTargetSource targetSource;

    @Bean(name = "task")
    @Scope("prototype")
    public MyTask createNewTask() {
        return new MyTask();
    }

    @Bean(name = "pool")
    public CommonsPoolTargetSource setupObjectPool() {
        CommonsPoolTargetSource pc = new CommonsPoolTargetSource();
        pc.setMaxSize(25);
        pc.setTargetBeanName("task");

        return pc;
    }

    @Bean(name = "pfb")
    public ProxyFactoryBean createProxyFactoryBean() {
        ProxyFactoryBean pfb = new ProxyFactoryBean();
        pfb.setTargetSource(setupObjectPool());

        return pfb;
    }

    private void go() {
        try {
            pooledTask.speak();

            // getting another object from pool
            MyTask someOtherTask = (MyTask) targetSource.getTarget();

            // returning the object to the pool
        targetSource.releaseTarget(someOtherTask);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I get multiple objects from the pool and release them ?

Comment: You would need to use the context for this: `MyTask task = (MyTask) context.getBean("pfb");`. Every call to `getBean` will borrow an object from the pool. To release them you get a hold of the pool object and call `releaseTarget` on it.

Comment: Is it possible to use the hold for borrowing an object instead of the context?

Comment: See my updated answer. I've defined a new `@Resource(name="pool")` to be injected and I used it in the 'go()' method.